# How to create imageView click event in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview

> **Note:** 
>       ImageView Click event is available in Android, I Want to know  whether it's available or not in iOS

I am new to iOS, please consider, I have camera image, OnClick of it I have to open my device camera, but I am getting function of Action for image. Attaching screenshot

[image: sample]

**My code:**

```
import UIKit

class AttendanceViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var loginimagebtn: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var loginstatus: UITextView!
    @IBOutlet weak var displayloginimg: UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    func openCamer() {


    if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(
        UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera) {

        let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
        imagePicker.delegate = self
        imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
        self.present(imagePicker,animated: true,completion : nil)
    }

}

    // For Toast message below code
    func showToast(message : String) {
        let toastLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: self.view.frame.size.width/2 - 75, y: self.view.frame.size.height-100, width: 150, height: 35))
        toastLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.6)
        toastLabel.textColor = UIColor.white
        toastLabel.textAlignment = .center;
        toastLabel.font = UIFont(name: "Montserrat-Light", size: 12.0)
        toastLabel.text = message
        toastLabel.alpha = 1.0
        toastLabel.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
        toastLabel.clipsToBounds  =  true
        self.view.addSubview(toastLabel)
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 4.0, delay: 0.1, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
            toastLabel.alpha = 0.0
        }, completion: {(isCompleted) in
            toastLabel.removeFromSuperview()
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: create the UIbutton (use setImage property) instead of UIimageview

Comment: @Anbu.karthik Thanks for you suggestion sir..let me check

Comment: are you want only camera or else

Comment: @Anbu.karthik yes sir...I have code how to open camera take photos no pbm...I need botton click for imageview

Comment: @Anbu.karthik How to set image inside UIbutton sir...I created button I did not find where to keep image

Comment: use button istead of uiimageview, set button custom image and set action of your button.

Comment: @ShauketSheikh ok sir...which means no attributes for Imageview onclick rights

Comment: there is way to set action on image view but that is not recommend for this type of work, so best to use UIButton

Comment: @Denis hello...Imageview setOnclick listener function available in Android..so I asked question where it's available or not in ios..

Comment: @GowthamanM, I didn't see anything like **so I asked question where it's available or not in iOS** i think you need to update your question.

Comment: @Denis thanks I updated

Comment: @Denis that is not fair. He says he is new to iOS. Reputation is not the benchmark for knowledge. You would also probably do the same if you were to code in Android or any other technology you are new to.

Comment: @RakeshaShastri, i saw it later after i commented.

Comment: Hi sir...can you tell me how to open front camera by default and please check my `openCamer()` function

Comment: i'm sorry, i haven't worked in anything involving a camera. I think @Anbu.karthik will be able to help you further. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

okay do the following step

**Step -1**

drag and drop UIbutton to the current viewcontroller

**Step -2**

delete the default title for your button

[image]

**step-3**

UIbutton has property **Image** --> go to image add your camera Image like follow and finally change the button frame based on your need

[image]

**Step - 4**

go to **connection Inspector** --> select your camera button event of **Touch Up Inside** and create the event for your button , for e.g

[image]

**option - 2**

if you want to proceed with your imageview I mean you dont  want to proceed with UIButton then follow this code

```
 let cameraTap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(cameraTapped))
    displayloginimg.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    displayloginimg.addGestureRecognizer(cameraTap)
```

and handle the event for your imageview

```
 @objc func cameraTapped() {
   // open your camera controller here
 }
```

Answer (score 6):

You can achieve this functionality on UIImageView using **UITapGestureRecognizer**.
Use below code in your **viewDidLoad()** method.

```
   override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            let tapGetsure = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self,
                                                    action: #selector(self.openCamer))
            tapGetsure.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
            loginimagebtn.gestureRecognizers = tapGetsure
            loginimagebtn.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    }
```

Comment: Hi sir...can you tell me how to open front  camera by default and please check my `openCamer()` function

Comment: sry sir....where to keep this line,,,I kept wrong place I think so for it's NSInvalidArgumentException  error please hel

Comment: @GowthamanM Keep this after imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera. Make sure you have added camera permission key in info.plist NSCameraUsageDescription